# Centos 8 Stream EOL

Tags: centos, centos8

I see [here](https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/) that EOL for Centos 8 Stream is 2024-05-31.
Probably I'm not getting something but I understand it is upstream of RHEL 8 which has EOL in 2029.
What's happening in 2024?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centos 8 Stream is a separate thing, not really trying to be a direct equivalent of RHEL 8 (not in terms of the packaged software or timeline).
Centos 8 (non-"stream") was supposed to track RHEL 8 and presumably would have matched the RHEL 8 EOL date if the project hadn't been killed off.

From the [Centos FAQ](https://centos.org/distro-faq/#q6-will-there-be-separateparallelsimultaneous-streams-for-8-9-10-etc) (emphasis added):

> #### Q6: Will there be separate/parallel/simultaneous streams for 8, 9, 10, etc?
>
> A: Each major release will have a branch, similar to how CentOS
> Linux is currently structured; however, CentOS Stream is designed to
> focus on RHEL development, so only the latest Stream will have the
> marketing focus of the CentOS Project.
>
> Because RHEL development cycles overlap, there will be times when
> there are multiple code branches in development at the same time.This
> allows users time to plan migrations and development work without
> being surprised by sudden changes.
>
> **Specifically, since the RHEL release cadence is every 3 years, and the
> full support window is 5 years, this gives an overlap of approximately
> 2 years between one stream and the next.**

Ie, the Centos 9 Stream should appear when RHEL 9 releases and coexist with Centos 8 Stream until RHEL 8 Full Support ends.
My understanding is that if you run Centos 8 Stream, you are expected to transition to Centos 9 Stream during that overlap (while [RHEL 8 continues to be maintained in it's Maintenance Support phase for another 5 years after that time](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#Overview)).

Comment: so, if I am using CentOS Steam 8 today by end of the year 2021 it will need to be purchased? do you know how much that would be?

Answer (score 1):

What will happen is RHEL 8 Full Support ends, which is the EOL for CentOS Stream 8.

CentOS Stream versions do not have a 10 year life, more like 5 years. As the testing repo for RHEL, Red Hat wants you to keep QAing features, and has no interest in providing 5 additional years of security updates for free.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!